# What is the recommended way to check that a list is a list of numbers in argument of a function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've been looking at the ways to check arguments of functions. I noticed that
`MatrixQ` takes 2 arguments, the second is a test to apply to each element.

But `ListQ` only takes one argument. (also for some reason, `?ListQ` does not have a help page, like `?MatrixQ` does).

So, for example, to check that an argument to a function is a matrix of numbers, I write

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[a_?(MatrixQ[#, NumberQ] &)] := Module[{}, a + 1]
```

What would be a good way to do the same for a List? This below only checks that the input is a List

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[a_?(ListQ[#] &)] := Module[{}, a + 1]
```

I could do something like this:

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[a_?(ListQ[#] && (And @@ Map[NumberQ[#] &, # ]) &)] := Module[{}, a + 1]
```

so that `foo[{1, 2, 3}]` will work, but `foo[{1, 2, x}]` will not (assuming `x` is a symbol). But it seems to me to be someone complicated way to do this.

**Question:** Do you know a better way to check that an argument is a list and also check the list content to be Numbers (or of any other Head known to Mathematica?)

**And a related question:** Any major run-time performance issues with adding such checks to each argument? If so, do you recommend these checks be removed after testing and development is completed so that final program runs faster? (for example, have a version of the code with all the checks in, for the development/testing, and a version without for production).

Comment: I also sometimes find myself wondering about the performance hit of this, *+1* for that question

Comment: Should I make the performance question part as a separate question or just leave it here?

Comment: I'd leave it here.  I highlighted them in bold because I think it's much easier to read and *notice* this way. Otherwise many people will never read that far.  If you don't accept my answer, the question will attract more views.

Comment: Are there cases where `ListQ` returns true for an expression whose head is not List? Otherwise I think `foo[a:{(_?NumberQ) ...}]` should work (untested!)

Comment: @celtschk Good point, `{___?NumberQ}` works too, why don't you post as an answer?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Because my comment contained a question (which was not meant rhetorical). I now took a quick Google to have the answer be "No", therefore I'll make it an answer now (using `___` because it's clearly better :-))

Comment: I guess most argument checks that we come up with have linear complexity in the size of the input. Algorithmic-complexity wise this will most likely not make your program perform worse (unless you have sorted lists and use binary search or other `log(n)` algorithms), but of course it's a few cycles over the data wasted checking things that are correct anyways in production code. You could do all the checking with the `?predicate` form and then define `predicate[x_] := True;` in production mode. Or specify arguments as `x : myPattern` and set `myPattern = _` in production.

Comment: Or you can automatically modify all `DownValues` to remove any argument patterns (unless they are needed to distinguish between overloaded versions of the same function).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding the performance hit (since your first question has been answered already) - by all means, do the checks, but in your top-level functions (which receive data directly from the user of your functionality. The user can also be another independent module, written by you or someone else). Don't put these checks in all your intermediate functions, since such checks will be duplicate and indeed unjustified.

*EDIT*

To address the problem of errors in intermediate functions, raised by @Nasser in the comments: there is a very simple technique which allows one to switch pattern-checks on and off in "one click". You can store your patterns in variables inside your package, defined prior to your function definitions.

Here is an example, where `f` is a top-level function, while `g` and `h` are "inner functions". We define two patterns: for the main function and for the inner ones, like so:

```
Clear[nlPatt,innerNLPatt ];
nlPatt= _?(!VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&);
innerNLPatt = nlPatt;
```

Now, we define our functions:

```
ClearAll[f,g,h];
f[vector:nlPatt]:=g[vector]+h[vector];
g[nv:innerNLPatt ]:=nv^2;
h[nv:innerNLPatt ]:=nv^3;
```

Note that the patterns are substituted inside definitions *at definition time*, not run-time, so this is exactly equivalent to coding those patterns by hand. Once you test, you just have to change one line: from

```
innerNLPatt = nlPatt
```

to

```
innerNLPatt = _
```

and reload your package.

A final question is - how do you quickly find errors? I answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560116/best-practices-in-error-reporting-mathematica/6563886#6563886), in sections *"Instead of returning `$Failed`, one can throw an exception, using Throw."*, and *"Meta-programming and automation"*.

*END EDIT*

I included a brief discussion of this issue in my book [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node520.html). In that example, the performance hit was on the level of 10% increase of running time, which IMO is borderline acceptable. In the case at hand, the check is simpler and the performance penalty is much less. Generally, for a function which is any computationally-intensive, correctly-written type checks cost only a small fraction of the total run-time.

A few tricks which are good to know:

- Pattern-matcher can be very fast, when used syntactically (no `Condition` or `PatternTest` present in the pattern).

For example:

```
randomString[]:=FromCharacterCode@RandomInteger[{97,122},5];
rstest = Table[randomString[],{1000000}];

In[102]:= MatchQ[rstest,{__String}]//Timing
Out[102]= {0.047,True}

In[103]:= MatchQ[rstest,{__?StringQ}]//Timing
Out[103]= {0.234,True}
```

Just because in the latter case the `PatternTest` was used, the check is much slower, because evaluator is invoked by the pattern-matcher for every element, while in the first case, everything is purely syntactic and all is done inside the pattern-matcher.

---

- The same is true for *unpacked* numerical lists (the timing difference is similar). However, for *packed* numerical lists, `MatchQ` and other pattern-testing functions don't unpack for certain special patterns, moreover, for some of them the check is *instantaneous*.

Here is an example:

```
In[113]:= 
test = RandomInteger[100000,1000000];

In[114]:= MatchQ[test,{__?IntegerQ}]//Timing
Out[114]= {0.203,True}

In[115]:= MatchQ[test,{__Integer}]//Timing
Out[115]= {0.,True}

In[116]:= Do[MatchQ[test,{__Integer}],{1000}]//Timing
Out[116]= {0.,Null}
```

The same, apparently, seems to be true for functions like `VectorQ`, `MatrixQ` and `ArrayQ` with certain predicates (`NumericQ`) - these tests are extremely efficient.

---

- A lot depends on how you write your test, i.e. to what degree you reuse the efficient Mathematica structures.

For example, we want to test that we have a real numeric matrix:

```
In[143]:= rm = RandomInteger[10000,{1500,1500}];
```

Here is the most straight-forward and slow way:

```
In[144]:= MatrixQ[rm,NumericQ[#]&&Im[#]==0&]//Timing
Out[144]= {4.125,True}
```

This is better, since we reuse the pattern-matcher better:

```
In[145]:= MatrixQ[rm,NumericQ]&&FreeQ[rm,Complex]//Timing
Out[145]= {0.204,True}
```

We did not utilize the packed nature of the matrix however. This is still better:

```
In[146]:= MatrixQ[rm,NumericQ]&&Total[Abs[Flatten[Im[rm]]]]==0//Timing
Out[146]= {0.047,True}
```

However, this is not the end. The following one is near instantaneous:

```
In[147]:= MatrixQ[rm,NumericQ]&&Re[rm]==rm//Timing
Out[147]= {0.,True}
```

Comment: If I understand you, isn't possible however that I do the checks only at the top function, but when making a call to my own lower level functions, from that top level function, a wrong matched argument (due to logic bug) is used in the call somewhere down stream? I can see myself, during development, changing the code, and passing the wrong parameter, and without these parameter checks on each function I use, I could overlook the error? Thanks

Comment: @Nasser I addressed your question in my edit, please have a look

Answer (score 13):

You might use `VectorQ` in a way completely analogous to `MatrixQ`.  For example,

```
f[vector_ /; VectorQ[vector, NumericQ]] := ...
```

Also note two differences between `VectorQ` and `ListQ`:

1. A plain `VectorQ` (with no second argument) only gives true if no elements of the list are lists themselves (i.e. only for 1D structures)
2. `VectorQ` will handle `SparseArray`s while `ListQ` will not

---

I am not sure about the performance impact of using these in practice, I am very curious about that myself.

Here's a naive benchmark.  I am comparing two functions: one that only checks the arguments, but does nothing, and one that adds two vectors (this is a very fast built-in operation, i.e. anything faster than this could be considered negligible).  I am using `NumericQ` which is a more complex (therefore potentially slower) check than `NumberQ`.

```
In[2]:= add[a_ /; VectorQ[a, NumericQ], b_ /; VectorQ[b, NumericQ]] :=
  a + b

In[3]:= nothing[a_ /; VectorQ[a, NumericQ], 
  b_ /; VectorQ[b, NumericQ]] := Null
```

Packed array.  It can be verified that the check is constant time (not shown here).

```
In[4]:= rr = RandomReal[1, 10000000];

In[5]:= Do[add[rr, rr], {10}]; // Timing

Out[5]= {1.906, Null}

In[6]:= Do[nothing[rr, rr], {10}]; // Timing

Out[6]= {0., Null}
```

Homogeneous non-packed array.  The check is linear time, but very fast.

```
In[7]:= rr2 = Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomInteger[10000, 1000000];

In[8]:= Do[add[rr2, rr2], {10}]; // Timing

Out[8]= {1.75, Null}

In[9]:= Do[nothing[rr2, rr2], {10}]; // Timing

Out[9]= {0.204, Null}
```

Non-homogeneous non-packed array.  The check takes the same time as in the previous example.

```
In[10]:= rr3 = Join[rr2, {Pi, 1.0}];

In[11]:= Do[add[rr3, rr3], {10}]; // Timing

Out[11]= {5.625, Null}

In[12]:= Do[nothing[rr3, rr3], {10}]; // Timing

Out[12]= {0.282, Null}
```

**Conclusion based on this very simple example:**

1. `VectorQ` is highly optimized, at least when using common second arguments.  It's much faster than e.g. adding two vectors, which itself is a well optimized operation.
2. For packed arrays `VectorQ` is constant time.

[@Leonid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786389/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-check-that-a-list-is-a-list-of-numbers-in-argumen/8787304#8787304) is very relevant too, please see it.

Comment: thanks, did not know about `VectorQ`. I should have type `?*Q` first to see all the `Q` type functions. I see so many of them now.

Answer (score 3):

Since `ListQ` just checks that the head is `List`, the following is a simple solution:

```
foo[a:{___?NumberQ}] := Module[{}, a + 1]
```

Comment: I just realized a deficiency of this when reading your answer "Since `ListQ` just checks that the head is `List`": both this and any `ListQ` solution will not work with `SparseArray`s.  `VectorQ` will.